# Firebase Realtime database not writing any values in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to insert data into realtime database but Firebase Realtime database not writing any values on my firebase account if i run another same program with different id its worked my code is...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mName, mSurname, mEmail;
    private Button submit;

    private FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference root = db.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mName = findViewById(R.id.name_edittext);
        mSurname = findViewById(R.id.surname_edittext);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email_edittext);

        submit = findViewById(R.id.Sumbit_btn);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                root.setValue(name);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

and my xml code is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/surname_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_edittext" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surname_edittext" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sumbit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_edittext" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and firebase rules is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true", 
  }
}
```

when i ran a program its showing no error but data not write its showing null in realtime databese

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation to see if something's wrong?

Comment: We've recently seen lots of folks struggling with database URL in their config file. Can you specify the database URL (you can find that in the Firebase console) in your code here: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("specify URL here")` to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to implement Frank van Puffelen suggestion? Does it work?

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working when i tried same code on another firebase account its working but here its not working only realtime database not working if i tried  firestore  and authentication its working fine i dont know why its happen to me